# Unable to map and unmarshal yaml array to golang struct

Tags: go

I want to unmarshal my `~/.kube/config` file into a `go` struct.

I am using the following approach

```
func ListContexts(pathToKubeConfig string) ([]string, error) {
    type Contexts struct {
        Ctx []string `yaml:"contexts"`
        //ApiVersion string              `yaml:"apiVersion"`
    }
    var ctx []string
    var c Contexts

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pathToKubeConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = yaml.Unmarshal(file, &c)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", c.Ctx)
    return ctx, nil
}
}
```

As is widely known, a kubeconfig file has the following struct:

```
apiVersion: v1
. . . 
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster1
    user: user1
  name: context1
- context:
    cluster: cluster2
    user: user2
  name: context2
```

My approach is printing:

```
[]string(nil)
```

Since `context` is a yaml array, why my mapping into a string array not working?

When I uncomment the `ApiVersion` field of my struct and try to print it, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context` is an array, but not a string array. Either use `[]map[string]interface{}` for context, or define the context as a struct, and use its array:

```
type context struct {
   Cluster string `yaml:"cluster"`
   ...
}

type contexts struct {
   Contexts []context `yaml:"contexts"`
}
```